# Using vagrant and vm for a magento localhost on windows 8.1

Tags: localhost, vagrant, ee-1.14.2.4

When i visit my `localhost:8080` i get the standard page like so:

It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

---

How come i'm not landing on the magento install page for EE?

I've tried changing my config.xml and local.xml files numerous times, but i guess i'm confused on what it should be.

Here is my config.xml file

```
        <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host>127.0.0.1:8080</host>
                <username/>
                <password/>
                <dbname>magento</dbname>
                <model>mysql4</model>
                <initStatements>SET NAMES utf8</initStatements>
                <type>pdo_mysql</type>
                <active>0</active>
                <persistent>0</persistent>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
```

my db name is magento. this is correct.

```
local.xml

<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date>{{date}}</date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key>{{key}}</key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix>{{db_prefix}}</table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host>{{localhost}}</host>
                    <username>{{user}}</username>
                    <password>{{**********}}</password>
                    <dbname>{{magento}}</dbname>
                    <initStatements>{{db_init_statemants}}</initStatements>
                    <model>{{db_model}}</model>
                    <type>{{db_type}}</type>
                    <pdoType>{{db_pdo_type}}</pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save>{{session_save}}</session_save>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName>{{admin_frontname}}</frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

my windows host file:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

when i'm in vagrant ssh and i go to etc/hosts

Here is what my file looks like:

```
vagrant@precise32:/etc$ cat hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       precise32

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

The page i want to run magento off is this: localhost:8080

How do i edit the above to fix that... sorry for all the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all ,did you created your virtual host on apache (on vagrant) ? 
You have to set the documentRoot to your app in your virtual host.
Basically u don't need to create your local.xml for an install, because this file will be created during the Magento install.

Comment: I did not do this yet. Completely forgot because it's not something I do all that often. Would you please be kind enough to refresh my memory on where and how to do this task. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I'm using apache.

Comment: in your /etc/hosts you have to write

your.vagrant.ip    your.project.dev  : example
192.168.33.10     myawesomeproject.dev

you can retrieve all this information in your vagrant file.

Comment: Make sure your virtual host is configured, on your vagrant. 
Make a vagrant ssh , and go to the folder /etc/apache/sites-available/
you should have your file config there... 
Make sure to enable your site after with cmd a2ensite  :)

Comment: Sorry to ask just a couple more questions @Sony. Inside my etc/apache2/sites-available I have these two files.  vagrant@precise32:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ ls
default  default-ssl <<<<   do i need to edit the default or create a new file?

Comment: I posted my code from  /etc/hosts above too... will you please have a look at it.. i'm still confused.... what/where is my vagrant ip?

Comment: You don't need to change your `etc/hosts` on vagrant.  You need to make change on your windows.  
How have you built your vagrant? from puphpet ? try to look for your `config.yaml`. In this file, you could find your vagrant ip. When you have it, add your vagrant ip and youawesomeproject.dev to your etc/hosts (on windows)
after look in /etc/apache2/sites-available  on vagrant, then make a `cp defaut yourawesomeproject.dev` and in this new file, configure your vhost, server name, document root , etc..    enable your site , restart apache et voila! :)

Comment: I'm not using puphpet. Will I still have a config.yaml file? I'll give this a shot tonight. Thank you for all your help. I know I'm really close to having this all ready.